# Is "per E-Mail" an English phrase

Tags: phrases

Is it correct to say:

> *"I'll send you this file per E-Mail"*?

Or

> *"Please send me this file per E-Mail"*?

I know most people say *"I'll send you this file by E-Mail"* or *"Please send me this file by E-Mail"*.

Is *"per E-Mail"* also correct?

Comment: Send it per fax.

Comment: It *sounds* [idiosyncratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiosyncrasy) to me, unless you have **requested *this file*** in which case it sounds like a valid ellipsis for per (your) E-Mail. I think, even then, it is still archaic per (your) question.

Comment: e-mail (or email) should not be capitalized there.

Comment: No, using *per* this way does not mean *by*; it means *according to*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could, but I think it's better to say *via* email. Although *per* has an archaic meaning of "by means of", it's not widely used.

Edit: As Jon Hanna points out in his comment below, "per" often shows up in "as per" (meaning "according to") in business language, as well as meaning "for each", and some of us (perhaps most of us) may not recognize either the meaning or the correctness of "per email" right off.

You likely want business language to be clear and unambiguous, and for there to be no question as to the correctness, so it's generally best to avoid this particular usage.

Comment: +1. My "reading brain" finds itself trying to apply another meaning of *per* and flailing at it. I think it is wanting to favour how *per* is used in "as per my email".

Comment: @Jon: +1 for your comment, but I'm not willing to upvote the answer itself because to *my* ear it sounds ridiculous to use ***per*** - which as OED says is *Now rare (chiefly archaic)* - in the context of something as modern as email. So for me, *"Yes, you could"* doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think we're differing on just how we're reading the *could* here. Because, well, they could indeed, they really shouldn't though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've run into this usage in the wild, though it sounds antiquated and a bit jarring next to email (or even E-Mail). Note that "sent per airmail" and "sent per messenger" get modest numbers of Google hits. I do think it's a correct English phrase, as the title asks, but it's not an particularly good one to use for this purpose.

Comment: Spehro: Well, I'm certainly not *downvoting* your "weak endorsement" of the usage. But I'd hazard a guess that most actual instances of *sent per email* are from less-than-competent writers, rather than deliberate choices made by people who're familiar with the dated/archaic usage. So I wouldn't encourage them by saying *you **could** use it*. But @Jon's 2nd comment is crucial here.